# Difference between "abbreviation" and "symbol" in scientific contexts

Tags: word-usage, science

I've noticed that the shorthand notations for chemical elements, such as `C` for carbon, are called *symbols*, not *abbreviations*. This also seems to be the case in several other scientific contexts, such as physical constants.

What special meaning does the term *symbol* carry in these contexts? How is a symbol distinct from an abbreviation?

Comment: Have you look up the two words in a dictionary?

Comment: When I worked in a lab, we used an abbreviation for a commonly encountered substance: '1010 acid'. (It was an acid (surprise) with a molecular weight of 1010.) You probably wouldn't find this abbreviation very easily outside labs dealing with antioxidant chemistry. But it was rarely if ever used in the representation of the molecules of derived compounds – the usual line-diagrams with letters for atoms other than carbon and hydrogen were used. For simpler molecules, line-diagrams with the symbols C, H, O, N, S ... are used. The usages spread way beyond normal textual ones.

Comment: @Kris: The notion of a symbol being universal was mentioned. The distinction was actually rather abstract and I didn't fully understand it. Also, many (but not all) scientific symbols actually look like abbreviations.

Comment: "symbols actually look like abbreviations:" so you do have an idea of the distinction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An abbreviation is a shortening of a word. An example of an abbreviation would be "intro." instead of "introduction". Another example would be the use of "Mr." for the word "Mister". In Medicine, "pre-op." is an abbreviation for pre-operative.  Note that abbreviations are followed by periods.

On the other hand, the word for the characters representing Chemical elements, and certain physical constants is "symbol". One reason for this is that while a some elements, such as Neon (NE), Nitogen (N), Carbon (C), and Oxygen (O) look like abbreviations, they are not written with periods (unless at the end of a sentence), and in some cases the symbol is not an abbreviation of the English name. The symbol for the element iron, for example, is Fe. Also, note that the symbol is universal. The symbol for iron in a scientific paper written in English is FE; so is the symbol in a scientific paper written in Spanish, where the word for iron is "Hiero", and in a scientific paper written in German, where the word for iron is "Eisen". Other common symbols which do not appear to be abbreviations in English are those for lead (Pb), and for Tin (Sn), and there are cases where the symbol that appears to be an abbreviation in English, like "O" for oxygen, would not appear to be an abbreviation. For example, the German word for Oxygen is "Sauerstoff".

Similarly with symbols for physical and mathematical constants. KN is universally known as a kilonewton, and R is universally known as the [Gas constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant).

Comment: +1 Nice answer - I'm not an expert in this field (massive understatement), but don't you need small case in [Ne] and [Fe]?

Comment: Auracaria, I'm not certain. I had advanced training in this field, but it's been a long time ago. I do remember seeing some of the symbols both ways, for example, Neon represented by both NE and Ne, but this may not be current practice (and may not, in fact, have been best practice when I saw them).

Comment: @brasshat What about physical units? For example, kg or cm are considered symbols although they can also be considered shortening of a word (e.g. kilogram).

Answer (score 2):

<sup>[Too long for a comment, but might be useful nonetheless]</sup>

The chemical symbols are **symbols because they are universal,** as brasshat has stated in [his answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/200939/18696).

However, they were originally **derived** as abbreviations — often from Latin. Fe for iron comes from *ferrum*; Pb for lead comes from *plumbum* (think *plumbing*); Sn for tin from *stannum*; C for carbon from *carbo* "coal"; there are many more examples.

H is an abbreviation of Lavoiser's French name for the element, which he derived from Greek.

Tungsten's symbol W is unusual though. *Tungsten* is a Swedish word, but its other name *wolfram* is derived from wolframite, tungsten's principal ore. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten#Etymology) has

> The name "tungsten" (from the Swedish *tung sten,* "heavy stone") is used in English, French, and many other languages as the name of the element, but not in the Nordic countries. Tungsten was the old Swedish name for the mineral scheelite. The other name "wolfram" (or "volfram"), is used in most European (especially Germanic and Slavic) languages, and is derived from the mineral wolframite, which is the origin of its chemical symbol, W. The name "wolframite" is derived from German "wolf rahm" ("wolf soot" or "wolf cream"), the name given to tungsten by Johan Gottschalk Wallerius in 1747. This, in turn, derives from "Lupi spuma", the name Georg Agricola used for the element in 1546, which translates into English as "wolf's froth", and is a reference to the large amounts of tin consumed by the mineral during its extraction.

The same has happened for SI units: the unit of energy is the joule, named after the English physicist James Joule; its **symbol,** derived from his name, is J.

Even the gas constant *R* mentioned by brasshat might be originally an abbreviation, or at least derived from a name. Wikipedia again:

> Some have suggested that it might be appropriate to name the symbol *R* the *Regnault constant* in honour of the French chemist Henri Victor Regnault, whose accurate experimental data was used to calculate the early value of the constant; however, the exact reason for the original representation of the constant by the letter *R* is elusive.

Thus although the letters are symbols (because they are universal), they had to come from somewhere. The particular choice of which letter to use is at least guided by some name relevant to the element or quantity, but it's not strictly an abbreviation.

Answer (score -2):

The term C for carbon **symbolises** carbon and can be **used as a shorthand** for carbon in a sentence. It's definitely an abbreviation but technically given the term symbol.

Symbol in chemistry == Abbreviation in English

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Posts input through the "Your Answer" box should only attempt to answer the question; you have merely repeated the OP's words. Please feel free to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.